# MacOS: Multiple python versions installed and unmanageable. Cleanup wanted

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tensorflow, pip

I've been on macOS for 2 years now and in the past year I've begun to work a lot in Python via VScode. But lately I have been running into so many problems because I didn't set up python properly from the start. I have multiple versions and modules installed globally (I know that is bad)... But I was wondering if anyone had advice about how I can clean up the Python set up so that there is the latest version being used and all modules will be installed properly.

I used homebrew as well and that is just adding to the mess. I want to do this right so that I can stop messing with configurations every day and just be able to develop.

I'll include some basic terminal outputs but if there is more that anyone would like to see I would be happy to provide more detail. If starting from scratch is the best thing to do then I'll do it. I don't know my way around all the configuration files and pathing so I'll need some help if that is what I'll have to do.

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ python --version
Python 2.7.16

$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.7

$ python3
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:33) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
>>> tensorflow.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py'
```

VScode has the following interpreters available (not sure if that helps)

- 2.7.16 /usr/bin/python
- 2.7.16 /System/Library/Frameworks....
- 3.7.3 /usr/bin/python3
- 3.7.7 /usr/local/bin/python3
- 3.7.7 /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7

Any help would be awesome!! I'm just tired of fighting with this and wanted to ask for help

Comment: do not touch the `usr/bin/python` or the `System/Library/Frameworks` python2.7 that is OS X python and removing it will cause serious problems

Comment: Your problem has a simple solution. Simply create a virtual environment (like with anaconda) and then take the pleasure of downloading your required tools in it as if it was just new. You can have multiple environments for multiple jobs. Like one environment for only python APIs or one for Machine Learning etc. This is the simplest way of being organized and having less and less bugs with packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having multiple versions of python is not really a propblem per se.

What I recommend is :

```
# In $HOME/.bashrc or .zshrc
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -fs python3 python
# Once the first and this step done, when you type [python],
# you'll be using /usr/local/bin/python3
```

As the first line of your python scripts, put :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

This way, you ensure your are always using the version /usr/local/bin/python3